# REACT_APP_* vs NODE_PATH Environment Variables

Tags: node.js, reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app

What is the difference between a regular CRA environment variable (that MUST begin with REACT_APP_) and the NODE_PATH variable (that is used to avoid having to use relative paths for imports, ../../../foo etc.)

From my testing, no variables can be used unless they begin with REACT_APP, so how is the NODE_PATH variable not ignored like other variables that do not begin with REACT_APP?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`NODE_PATH` is accessible because it's added in the Webpack configuration in `react-scripts`.

You can see the code that adds it here:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/25184c4e91ebabd16fe1cde3d8630830e4a36a01/packages/react-scripts/config/env.js#L61

You'll see in that file that you can also set `NODE_ENV` which sets which environment you are running in (e.g. `development`, `staging`, etc.) as well as `PUBLIC_URL`

To answer your question on the differences:

`NODE_PATH` allows you to use absolute paths for imports. For example, you can set your `NODE_PATH` to the following:`NODE_PATH=src:src/components:src/containers` and then in your React code you could write something like this: `import Button from 'button'` instead of `import Button from '../../../button'` as long as you have that module in one of the folders `src`, `src/components`, or `src/containers` because create-react app will look for the `button` module those folders. You wouldn't actually use the `NODE_PATH` variable in your React code that same way that you use `REACT_APP_*` variables. Basically, it tells your app where to look for modules.

`REACT_APP_*` variables are injected into your application at build time using the Webpack configuration from the file I linked to.

This: `const GRAPHQL_URI = REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_URI`

becomes this: `const GRAPHQL_URI = https://example.com`

if you have this in your `.env` file: `REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_URI = https://example.com`

Comment: REACT_APP_testing=test works but NODE_PATH=src dont let me import